# Oracle mask multiple instances of a set of characters in a string - multiple variations of "phrase to be masked " in the string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am attempting to mask multiple instances of a set of characters in a string.

The most likely variations of the string are

- BL-nn-nnnnnnn
- BLnn-nnnnnnn
- BLnnnnnnnnn
- BL-nnnnnnnnn

and mask all with `'BL-XX-XXXXXXX '` (note the space character at end of the masked string) there are other words that can start with BL in the string as well.

---

Any help with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In your example data, does `n` represent a decimal digit, or is it the literal character `'n'`?

Comment: n is a number between 0-9

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(TEST_DATA, 'BL[-0-9 ]+', 'BL-XX-XXXXXXX ')
```

seems to do what you want.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d547d20ae62d6208a983227c67e5ec4e)

Comment: thank you for your help -YOU are a STAR!- this works well for me -

Answer (score 0):

First remove all dashes and format by using `regexp_replace()` with `[[:alnum:]]` pattern to represent numeric or digit characters:

```
select regexp_replace(replace(str,'-',''), 'BL([[:alnum:]]{2})([[:alnum:]]{7})','BL-\1-\2 ')  
       as "Result String"
  from tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=286e04a94d41fde460e6da458c0187be)</kbd>